# Is torchmetrics mean average precision behaving as expected? 2 images assessed individually score higher than the result together

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, object-detection, metrics, torch

I'm trying to evaluate the performance of an object detection model using [torchmetrics mean average precision](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/detection/mean_average_precision.html). However, I'm getting this odd result:

When I evaluate the metric for image A, I get 'map': 0.7891, 'map_50': 1, 'map_75': 1

When I evaluate the metric for image B, I get 'map': 0.7611, 'map_50': 1, 'map_75': 1

When I run the metric for a list containing information about both image A and image B, I expect the performance to be somewhere between 0.7891 and 0.7611. Instead, I get 'map':0.7197, 'map_50': 0.9293,'map_75': 0.9293.

Is my reasoning about how mean average precision for multiple images works flawed, or is something going wrong here?

Here are the specific values I'm using:

```
import torch
from torchmetrics.detection.mean_ap import MeanAveragePrecision

include_A = True
include_B = True

truth_eval = []
pred_eval = []

if include_A:
  truth_eval.append({'boxes': torch.tensor([[562., 180., 694., 227.],
          [322., 189., 467., 251.],
          [770., 167., 954., 240.]], dtype=torch.float64),
  'labels': torch.tensor([1., 1., 1.], dtype=torch.float64)})
  pred_eval.append({'boxes': torch.tensor([[ 769.4067,  163.4746,  949.1498,  240.5295],
          [ 574.9888,  178.3064,  697.7145,  226.6653],
          [ 333.8886,  188.9244,  471.6525,  250.9485],
          [1037.9913,   20.9808, 1110.0175,  118.0723]]),
  'scores': torch.tensor([1., 1., 1., 1.]),
  'labels': torch.tensor([1., 1., 1., 1.])})

if include_B:
  truth_eval.append({'boxes': torch.tensor([[554., 180., 688., 228.],
          [309., 190., 457., 253.],
          [810., 166., 999., 239.]], dtype=torch.float64),
  'labels': torch.tensor([1., 1., 1.], dtype=torch.float64)})
  pred_eval.append({'boxes': torch.tensor([[ 567.4130,  177.8370,  691.1442,  227.1231],
          [ 810.1462,  163.8314,  994.3475,  241.7314],
          [ 321.8360,  190.0476,  464.3474,  251.8763],
          [1046.0631,   18.7516, 1111.9734,  104.2167],
          [ 540.7168,   76.8780,  564.6191,  133.8904]]),
  'scores': torch.tensor([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]),
  'labels': torch.tensor([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])})

metric = MeanAveragePrecision()
metric.update(pred_eval , truth_eval )
metric.compute()
```